# WordPress: How should I add my line to phpMyAdmin table to show up in user profile?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to figure out if I need to create a new database table, or should just use the `wp_users` table that already exists to have it where a users favorite color shows up in their profile page (on the front end). Any help?

**MY GOAL:**

My goal is to add a column `favorite_color` (for example). This way when I either create a new page that only displays this information, or when I go into the WooCommerce My Account page, that users favorite color shows to them.
(NOTE: my intent is to not allow the user to make any changes themselves, but to update this favorite number through uploading a CSV or text file, or some method to mass update each user's fields.)

**WHY:**

I need to mass update their colors regularly, because their favorite color will change each month, and each person will guaranteed be a different color from one another that I will chose for them. I can also make up colors on the fly. There are no rules so a second table of all the colors in the world are NOT necessary.

I am thinking that adding a new column to the `wp_users` table shouldn't hurt anything. Or should it be a in a separate/different table?

**AFTER I KNOW THE PROPER METHOD:**

After I know the proper method of how to add the field to a table, it is my belief that either through editing the WooCommerce My Accounts page or through creating a new page, I can show the favorite color to the logged in users by using the following code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_table_name";
// this will get the data from my table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
?>
<ul>
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $retrieved_data->favorite_color;?></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to add the user's favorite color as a new user meta row in the wp_usermeta table:

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/

The link above has some functions and references for adding, updating, and getting usermeta. That way, you don't have to mess with the wp_users table at all and potentially break things.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a pain to update the table though if you are trying to do mass updates? My thought is mass updates would then be impossible, am I incorrect?

I say this since there can be multiple fields with the same user_id in the usermeta table. So uploading a spreadsheet would be out of the question.

Comment: Not necessarily. Yes, there's lots of rows in the usermeta table that can correspond to one user_id, but the meta_key is what matters. Your meta_key would be something like favorite_color, and you'd use updade_user_meta based on that meta_key. You could even use a plugin to do the heavy lifting for you. https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-user-metadata/#description